# What is the possibility of an ITM covered call not being assigned?

Tags: options

I wrote 70, 1/17/20 Apple covered calls at $240. Apple went to $310. It is 1/18 and the calls have expired but I still have my stock. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to expiration, option exercises are submitted during the day and processed by the OCC after the market closes.  The investor receives assignment notification the morning of the next business day.

In the case of  Friday expiration, exercise of ITM options occurs that evening and investors receive Monday morning  assignment notification.